# Install the low version tesseract there is an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Brew Install

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/8ba134eda537d2cee7daa7ebdd9f728389d9c53e/Library/Formula/tesseract.rb

Updating Homebrew...

################################################################## 100.0%

```
Error: Calling Resource#sha1 is disabled!
Use Resource#sha256 instead.
/Users/huzige/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/tesseract.rb:123:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Tesseract>'
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to install an obsolete formula version which isn't working because they no longer allow the sha1 hashes that they used to use.

Comment: Yes, but the OCR does not support the latest version，Need to be installed to run an old version。The new version is not working